# On the lattice structures of graphite

Tags: solid-state-physics

My question is the following:

**What causes graphite to have either a cubic lattice structure or a hexagonal lattice structure? Does it depend on how it is grown? Or is it a random process?**

I would also like to know if anyone has any good reading on the solid state physics of graphite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some materials can occur in several crystal structures if the formation energy is similar. In fact, what matters is the formation energy (difference) at the temperature, where synthesis is performed (typically at higher temperature). Depending on the particular composition, some materials exhibit phase transitions, when brought back to ambient conditions. Others can be "frozen" in a state, which actually would not be stable at room temperature, which is then called meta-stable.

For the case of carbon:
Graphite is the stable configuration at ambient conditions. Diamond is meta-stable, although the energy barrier for the transition to graphite is high enough, so the transformation occurs only at a very slow rate. The cubic lattice of diamond becomes favourable at high temperatures and pressures.

Answer (score 1):

Graphite has a hexagonal lattice structure due to its $sp^2$ hybridisation. However, diamonds are cubic lattices due to their $sp^3$ hybridisation.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, which asks for the physical conditions that will decide which lattice structure (and therefore which type of hybridization) will occur.